# Как сделать TextBox растягивающимся?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

использую `.Net Framework (compact Edition)` для мобильного приложения.

На форме есть `TextBox`, который должен растягиваться в случаях, когда строка превышает ширину элемента.

Параметры в дизайнере у элемента `TextBox` :

```
this.txbValue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 21);
this.txbValue.Multiline = true;
this.txbValue.Name = "txbValue";
this.txbValue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 22);
```

Растягивать я пробовал так:

```
private void txbValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateValuesList();
    using (Graphics gr = ((TextBox)sender).CreateGraphics())
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Height = (int)gr.MeasureString(((TextBox)sender).Text, Font).Height;
    }
}
```

Но это не сработало.
Подскажите как правильно растягивать `TextBox` в случаях, если строка больше ширины элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты меряешь и изменяешь ВЫСОТУ, а не ширину.

```
private void txbValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sndr = (TextBox)sender;

    UpdateValuesList();

    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
    {
        SizeF size = gr.MeasureString(sndr.Text, sndr.Font, GraphicsUnit.Point));

        sndr.Width = size.Width;
    }
}
```

Comment: поменял и это не работает по какой-то причине

Comment: обновил ответ, пробуй

Comment: Результат тот же, почему-то он не расширяется и не меняет свои размеры. т.е. это просто не работает

Comment: поставь брейкпоинт внутри юзинга. Брейкпоинт останавливается там? Какая ширина внутри сайз?

Comment: {Width=186,9659, Height=13,82519}

Comment: А если просто присвоить другой размер вручную в конце метода....  "sndr.Width = 200;" срабатывает?

Comment: Результат тот же

Comment: Если повторишь на пустом проекте, код должен сработать. Проблема явно внешняя и никак не отображается в самом вопросе. Нужно что бы ты отдебажился и понял где именно срабатывает изменение размера на изначальное после изменений данного кода.

Comment: Переписал заново, размер чуть побольше поставил на 400 и он поменял ширину TextBox'а

Comment: А какой пул манипуляций нужно сделать, для того, чтобы увеличивалась высота, при условии, что ширина текста больше, чем ширина `TextBox`?

Comment: не понимаю вопроса

Comment: ну т.е. я хотел бы, что бы мой `TextBox` увеличивался не в ширину , а в высоту, вот и всё

Comment: держи https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893059/autoresize-textbox-control-vertically